# How to show binary search tree results in arrays?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is my program, but I don't know how to show the binary search tree results in array (one dimensional). I use random as inputs. How to show binary search tree results in arrays? Help me please.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct BstNode{
    int data;
    BstNode* left;
    BstNode* right;
};

BstNode* GetNewNode(int data){
    BstNode* newNode = new BstNode();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

BstNode* Insert(BstNode* root, int data){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data <= root->data){
        root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else{
        root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}


int main(){
    int x, i, n, data;
    BstNode* root = NULL;
    cout<<"The number of data : ";cin>>n; 
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        data=(rand()%100+1);
        cout<<data<<" ";  
        Insert(root,data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know C++ has classes, right?

Comment: Maybe you want to google 'heap sort'?

Comment: We don't use classes in C++ yet.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. A binary search tree is an ordered group of nodes, each with a left and right pointer to a child node (or NULL). An array is a contiguous block of memory. You can convert a tree into the equivalent of a linked list by only using one of the pointers in each node, usually the right one (so that data order is smallest to largest).

Comment: How to display array values ​​based on the position DBST? For example, 10 is the root; 5 is the left child; 20 is the right child; 2 is the left child of 5; 25 is the right child of 20. The result: 10 5 20 2 null null 25

Comment: The result shows as an array one dimensional.

Comment: You can do a breadth-first traversal, the general algorithm of which [**can be seen here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_2).

Comment: I think OP is looking to populate an array with the contents of BST as obtained though inorder walk.

Answer (score 1):

I guess OP is looking to fill an array with the elements of BST as observed in in-order traversal. If so, we can try something like the following.

```
void
fillArrayInorder( BstNode const * pCurr, int * pArr, int & arrIdx ) { 
    if( pCurr ) {
        fillArrayInorder( pCurr->left, pArr, arrIdx );
        pArr[ arrIdx++ ] = pCurr->data;
        fillArrayInorder( pCurr->right, pArr, arrIdx );
    }
}
```

Call it as

```
int arr[ MAX_ELEMS ];
int arrIdx = 0;
fillArrayInorder( root, & arr, arrIdx );
```

Note: Instead of the raw array, it might be better to use a `vector` and its `push_back()` method, so that the length and index updating complexity is not necessary in the application code.